# iReport + XPath - Sum String Column

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports, sum, ireport

I'm building a report where I have a subreport. This subreport brings some data through XPath, this means it's everything strings from a XML. One of the columns of this subreport has some values, where I need do sum them and show in the end of the table.

I don't know how to put this to work. I've tried to create a variable with sum parameter, but it does not work.

Did anybody need this before?

Scenario:
I load a lot of values from a XPath query, e.g:
/something/something1/something2

This query returns some fields according to my needs. With them I build a table (in a subreport). The problem is: the last column (4), values are strings from XML.

*`iReport version: 3.0.0`*

Really thanks!

Comment: You have not provided enough information for an answer.

Comment: What else do you need? I can provide if necessary.

Comment: @axcdnt `I've tried to create a variable with sum parameter, but it does not work.` - What do you mean? What is the problem?

Comment: @axcdnt It will be better to post the snippet of subreport's jrxml file.

Comment: I've found the solution. I'll be posting it, as soon as StackOverflow allow me. Thanks!

Comment: @axcdnt You can add the word "Solved" to the question's title. And add solution to the question's text. If you wish...

Comment: Thanks @AlexK Check the solution and check if you get it. It was more simple than I thought.

Comment: @AlexK: Please do not add the word "SOLVED" to question titles.  That's what the answer checkbox is for.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

What I needed? According to the original post, a column with strings read from a XML through XPath and a footer with the sum.

Result from column SUM

What to do? Create a variable where you'll keep your sum. After created, edit it. e.g:enter image description here

Fill variable expression with the format you need. Here I used

```
new BigDecimal($F{theFieldToSum});
```

Click ok. Now the variable is created, you must create a new TextField where you'll show your sum. Create it and edit it. Here I used the following format:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($V{theVariableYouCreatedBefore})
```

Click "Apply" and that's all. Compile your report and now you'll have the expected result. For sure, you can do some adapt, but in general this is the process.